# How to find out current working directory in Bamboo?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

This seemed like a good idea at the time

```
public static final String MY_CONFIG_FILE = System.getenv("APP_HOME") 
                                              + "/cfg/app.properties";
```

When pushed code to Bamboo some tests failed with

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./cfg/app.properties (No such file or directory)
```

I did set EnvironmentVariable in Bamboo as `APP_HOME=.`

Still, however, Bamboo can't seem to find the file. What am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case someone is interested, **in order to reference current working directory**,  `APP_HOME` should be set to:

```
APP_HOME=${bamboo.build.working.directory}
```